# I have multiple entry and exit status of a person. how do i get the last status of single person

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have a table in sql in following format

```
Userid  Status  Logtime
1         In    10:10
1         In    10:12
2         In    10:14
3         In    10:16
3         Out   10:18
1         Out   10:20
4         In    10:22
2         Out   10:24
```

Output required

```
Userid  Status  In_time Out_time
1         out            10:20
2         In    10:14    10:24
3         In    10:16    10:18
4         In    10:22
```

Comment: What's the datatype of the `Logtime` field?

Comment: Expected output need to be reviewed as No in for user id 1 and no out for user id 2. Why? Also why entity-framework tag has been tagged?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code started? SO is meant to help find answers not to do your job for you

Comment: why UserId 1 don't have in_time in your requirement

Comment: In_Time should be the first instead of the last status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`In_Time` should be the first instead of the last status.

Then your result should be instead

Userid   IN_TIME OUT_TIME

```
1       10:10   10:20
2       10:14   10:24
3       10:16   10:18
4       10:22   NULL
```

Code like below, live demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25d80512b2ba6878eef1d5e872647e7c)

```
SELECT Userid,
MIN(CASE WHEN sStatus = 'IN' THEN Logtime ELSE NULL END) AS IN_TIME, 
MAX(CASE WHEN sStatus = 'Out' THEN Logtime ELSE NULL END) OUT_TIME
FROM TblInOut
GROUP BY Userid
```

**Updated**

If you want to get the last status for `In_Time`, just adjust slightly condition from `Min` to `Max` like below, live demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8e6eae932d385ed468e01660ab7cd5b)

```
SELECT Userid,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sStatus = 'IN' THEN Logtime ELSE NULL END) AS IN_TIME, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN sStatus = 'Out' THEN Logtime ELSE NULL END) OUT_TIME
FROM TblInOut
GROUP BY Userid
```

**Output**

```
Userid  IN_TIME OUT_TIME
1       10:12   10:20
2       10:14   10:24
3       10:16   10:18
4       10:22   NULL
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Kamalpreet Singh

Comment: It depends upon the requirement & can be modified query accordingly.

Comment: Yes, just use `Min` `Max` to be able to resolve the problem :)

Comment: Thanks it also fills the requirement. How can i count the number of persons are inn and out at current time.

Comment: Give me your sample data with the corresponding result. It's usually a good idea to post another question then tag me to help you. You should resolve one problem that is described on the post @Kamalpreet Singh

Comment: I have crossed my limit of asking question. The sample data is same you have used earlier but i forgot to add it in the above question. The output like "No. of persons Inn:3, No. of person Out: 1 and Total persons :4 ". your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: here you are https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f561701143cb45fa22915f097325815

Comment: @KamalpreetSingh . . . I'm surprised you accepted this answer.  It doesn't provide the last status, which seems like an important part of your question.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I've explained for OP the reason why he should get the first time for `In_Time` and he accepted that *Thanks it also fills the requirement*. BTW, I've just updated my answer with more details (If OP want to get the last status for `In_Time`). Please take a look.

Comment: I am trying to join the query "SELECT elog.UserId,MIN(CASE WHEN elog.[C1] = 'IN' THEN elog.[LogDate] ELSE NULL END) AS IN_TIME, MAX(CASE WHEN elog.[C1] = 'Out' THEN elog.[LogDate] ELSE NULL END) OUT_TIME, emp.EmployeeName
FROM  Employees as emp JOIN   EmployeeLogs as elog ON emp.EmployeeCode = elog.UserId 
where convert(varchar(10),elog.LogDate,111) = Convert(date, getdate())  
GROUP BY elog.UserId" but i am getting this error "Column ' elog.UserId ' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.". what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
Create table TblInOut(Userid int, sStatus Varchar(10),  Logtime Varchar(10))
insert into TblInOut Values(1, 'In', '10:10'), (1, 'In', '10:12'), (2, 'In', '10:14'), (3, 'In', '10:16'), (3, 'Out', '10:18'),
(1, 'Out', '10:20'), (4, 'In', '10:22'), (2, 'Out', '10:24')

select Userid, 
       max(case when sStatus = 'In' then Logtime end) as INTIME,
       max(case when sStatus = 'Out' then Logtime end) as OUTIME
from (select t.*, 
             row_number () over (order by Cast(Logtime as Time)) as seq1,
             row_number () over (partition by Userid order by Cast(Logtime as Time)) as seq2
      from TblInOut t
     ) t
group by Userid;
```

It will give the output as below. Here is the [demo given](https://rextester.com/IWDH63449).

```
Userid  INTIME  OUTIME
----------------------
1       10:12   10:20
2       10:14   10:24
3       10:16   10:18
4       10:22   NULL
```

**Edit**

To check the in for specific period you can use the below query. If you want to check the user and total count only for out then change the having clause status with `Out`.

```
select Userid, 
       max(case when sStatus = 'In' then Logtime end) as INTIME,
       max(case when sStatus = 'Out' then Logtime end) as OUTIME,
       Count(*) as TotalInOut
from TblInOut t
group by Userid having max(case when sStatus = 'In' then Logtime end) between Cast('10:10' as Time) and Cast('10:18' as Time);
```

If you want a person has done `in` and also `out` for specific period then you can use having clause as below.

```
having max(case when sStatus = 'In' then Logtime end) between Cast('10:10' as Time) and Cast('10:18' as Time)
    and max(case when sStatus = 'Out' then Logtime end) between Cast('10:10' as Time) and Cast('10:18' as Time);
```

You can also use the `OR` operator to check either in or out for specific period of time in above having clause.

> You can use Min() for the in as suggested and Max() for out.
>   To join the query with the other tables you can follow this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ee2ff3e1efcb8b212ad1f15dfddc586)

Comment: thanks for the help. Can i further count the that how many person are inn and outt at current time

Comment: You can use count & pass the filter condition. You can post another question for this.

Comment: `In_Time` should be the first time. How do you think about it? @Suraj Kumar. Anyway +1

Comment: it fine, now i only required is the number of persons Inn and out at certain amount of time. sorry i have crossed my limit of asking questions. you help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. can you tell me how do i join with another table, i am trying the same but getting and errror: "Column ' elog.UserId ' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." what needs to be done.

Comment: @KamalpreetSingh Post your query I will try to modify & help or you can also post the separate question.

Comment: Sorry i have crossed my limit of asking question. 
The Query is: "SELECT elog.UserId,MIN(CASE WHEN elog.[C1] = 'IN' THEN elog.[LogDate] ELSE NULL END) AS IN_TIME, MAX(CASE WHEN elog.[C1] = 'Out' THEN elog.[LogDate] ELSE NULL END) OUT_TIME, emp.EmployeeName, emp.Gender, emp.ContactNo, emp.FatherName
FROM  Employees as emp JOIN   EmployeeLogs as elog ON emp.EmployeeCode = elog.UserId where convert(varchar(10),elog.LogDate,111) = Convert(date, getdate())  GROUP BY elog.UserId"

Comment: @KamalpreetSingh You can check this - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ee2ff3e1efcb8b212ad1f15dfddc586

Comment: thanks a lot. i works fine. how can i get single column from another table.

Comment: @KamalpreetSingh In outer query you can try this like - Select Employee.EmployeeId, Employee.Name, a.* from(..................